# Should we merge the tag "written-conventions" into "orthography"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We have two tags:

- [written-conventions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/written-conventions) - 15 questions, no tag wiki
- [orthography](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography) - 78 questions, has a tag wiki

I don't really see a reason to keep *written-conventions* as a separate tag.  It seems to cover pretty much the same topic.

Should I merge this tag into *orthography*?  Or is there a difference I don't know about?

Comment: We also have a _spelling_ tag, which could also be merged into _orthography_. All (on-topic) questions about spelling will be about Japanese orthography, so...

Comment: The only complaint I have is that "orthography" is a rather technical term, but I don't have a better suggestion.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie But [tag synonyms appear "live"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/i8zLN.png) when selecting the tag and the tag excerpt should explain the word orthography enough for someone to choose it. How about renaming _written-conventions_ to _writing-conventions_ before merging?

Comment: That seems reasonable to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm for merging (and keeping [orthography](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography) as main tag).

(I haven't found much about what "written conventions" is supposed to mean in English. In fact, our little tag [written-conventions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/written-conventions) is on the first page of Google's search results for `"written conventions"`. "Writing conventions" seems to be used synonymously with orthography, although some websites suggest it may also include grammar, but for questions about grammar we have [grammar](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) already.)

Comment: Okay!  :-)  I renamed *written-conventions* to *writing-conventions*, then merged it into *orthography*.